# Нужно дополнить Get запрос

Tags: php, html

Есть ссылка на список товаров:

```
index.php?page=filter&option=opt1
```

Начал писать код пагинации:

```
$row_cnt = $query->num_rows
$count = ceil($row_cnt / 10);
if(isset($_GET['pagenum'])) {
$num = $_GET['pagenum'];
} else {
$num = 1;
}
for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {
echo "<div class='num'><a href=''>" . $i . "</a></div>";
}
```

Код не дописал, ибо, что не делал, Get запрос в ссылке заменяется новым из блока пагинации, по типу:

```
index.php?pagenum=1
```

Где может быть ошибка и что можно сделать, чтобы просто дополнить уже существующие параметры?

Должно выйти что-то вроде:

```
index.php?page=filter&option=opt1&pagenum=1
```

Comment: Ну и почему href пустой?

Comment: я без понятия что туда записать, чтобы все красиво вышло((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [http_build_query](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.http-build-query.php)

```
$params = $_GET;
$params['pagenum'] = $i;
$query = http_build_query($params);
```

Comment: Благодарствую примного) проблема решена.